# Generating a COM visible assembly from managed c++ (C++/CLI)

Tags: com, interop, c++-cli, managed-c++

I need to develop some classes that should be callable from VB6 with Managed C++ (C++/CLI).

I've developed first a sample in C# and I can use the assembly through COM without problems 
just using the setting "Register for COM interop" and "Make assembly COM visible" (and using the attribute [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] to make methods available at VB6.

After that I tried to translate the sample to C++/CLI without success. I've created the same class with the [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)] attribute. I've set the "Embedded IDL" setting to specify the output TLB but the TLB is not generated automatically. If I use the tlbexp util over the generated DLL I get a tlb that can be imported at VB6 but when I try to create an instance I get an "ActiveX compoennt can't create object (429)"

What more do I need to do with the project to let it run?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much to go on but you never mentioned registering the assembly.  The C++ IDE doesn't have the "Register for COM interop" option.  From the Visual Studio Command Prompt, run Regasm.exe on the assembly to get it registered.  You need the /codebase option if you don't put the assembly in the GAC.  And the /tlb option generates the type library, making tlbexp.exe unnecessary.

Comment: I'm registering the assembly automatically with tlbexp, right? The /tlb option is reported as unrecognized by the compiler and the linker. Are you sure about that?

Comment: No, tlbexp only generates a type library, nothing is getting registered.  The /tlb option is for Regasm.exe, not the compiler or linker.  It puzzles me greatly that you didn't get that from my post.

Comment: It has to be something related with here being a bit late. I've reread your post and I'm as puzzled as you :)